# Powershell Invoke-Command ASPX/C# vs. Commandline

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, powershell-2.0, invoke-command

So I try to invoke a PS script from a ASPX/C# application. When I run the PS script from commandline (`PS C:\scripts> ./do-barrelRoll.ps1 -s remoteComputer`) it works as expected. But when I use C# it cannot connect to the remote computer (wrong user/password). Fun fact: The user and password to use are inside a config section in the PS script itself (see `$SETUP` variable)! What am I doing wrong?

Exact error message from ASPX (the server name is correct!):

```
[remoteComputer] Connecting to remote server remoteComputer failed with the following error message : The user name or password is incorrect
```

Relevant parts of the PS Script:

```
set-alias new New-Object
$passwd = $SETUP["password"] | ConvertTo-SecureString -asplaintext -force
$session = new -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $SETUP["user"], $passwd

Invoke-Command –ComputerName $PARAM["s"] -Credential $session –ScriptBlock {
    # Do a barrel roll
}
```

Relevant parts of ASPX/C# application:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

public ActionResult doAction(string server, string action)
{
    var split = server.Split(';');
    //...
    var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -f; C:\\scripts\\do-barrelRoll.ps1 -s " + split[1]);
    Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
    // Here I retrive the results and the content of the error stream and display them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected at the command line most likely because your account has full script access and can run everything.  The account that .NET runs under should be more constrained.  You'll have to check that the account has rights to run unrestricted scripts.  Check local policies and then go up from there.  You most likely are not the same account that the .NET application is running as.

Comment: Yeah, but the credentials to use are inside the PS script... Also I elevate the process' rigths just before executing the script. The script does defenitly run (see error message)

Comment: @MarcoAlka It's not about the credentials you have inside your script, it's the process that is running the executing script that you need to pay attention to.  In most secure environments, unrestricted scripts are disabled by default.

Comment: But why does it complain about Username/Password then? I ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy -f unrestricted` on the server running the .NET application and on the target server. The problem persists.